# Linux Firewall + Loadbalancer distribution

Tags: linux, firewall, load-balancing

Can anyone recommend a Linux specialized distribution (or appliance) which provides both Firewall and Load-balancer?

Something similar to IPCop for example, but containing LB as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opensource firewall [pfsense](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Inbound_Load_Balancing) can do load balancing (see the link).   They have a VMWare appliance. You can buy commerical support etc.  It's based on FreeBSD though so if you have some absolute requirement for it to run on Linux then it may not be suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks nice!

Any idea how the it compares to HAProxy?

Comment: I'd say pfsense is a firewall that load balancing as a feature. Haproxy is a dedicated load balancer so if you used pfsense then you'd probably meet the end of the load balancer capabilities if you are doing anything special which haproxy might provide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any (but I haven't really looked either) distributions that specializes in these unless you want to start paying some money. (F5 LTM for example). But any decent linux distribution can do both of these things easily. There are lots of free load balancing apps out there that run on Linux:

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/
http://www.ultramonkey.org/
http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/
http://www.inlab.de/balance.html

And the firewall (iptables) part is just part of any standard Linux distro. There are also lots of apps out there to help simplify configuration of this too.

Answer (score 0):

Not an appliance as such, but Shorewall does a good job to balance load over multiple connections. It can route traffic based on source, destination, port etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

yo can use ZEN load balancer, distro based on debian, actually you can configure balancing over WEB GUI and firewall over iptable binary.

http://zenloadbalancer.sourceforge.net

you can subscribe to mailing list support

Regards